# project PROJECT called with incorrect number of arguments

Tags: cmake, qt5

when I enter the console:

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

error occurs:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 5 (project):   project PROJECT called
>   with incorrect number of arguments
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 19 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   requested
>   CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
>   CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
>   of the following names:
>
> ```
> Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
> qt5gui-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
>   "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
>   "Qt5Gui"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has been   installed.

on the forums write that this is due to the fact that not installed qt5-defult and gt5-dev-tools, but before the installation and after nothing has changed what to do?

Comment: The two errors you're getting here are pretty specific, and the second error actually tells you what to do, what's the issue? Can you post your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmakelists-txt/files/CMakeLists.txt/download

Comment: Unfortunately I can't download it from where I am right now. Can you update your question and just add the CMakeLists.txt file as a code snippet? It would help others viewing the question too as they will be able to just see the code and tell you where your issue is. I've worked quite a bit with Qt and CMake so I have a pretty good idea what the issue is but I need to be able to see what you're attempting to do first.

Comment: He is not being added because of the large number of characters

Comment: **Code snippet**. It's not necessary to post the entire file if it's very large. You're only getting errors from lines 5 and 19 at the moment, you can very easily break it down to post ~5-10 lines of code in a single code section. Unfortunately not many people will be able to help you if you can't post what's causing the problem. The error messages you're getting are pretty specific and that's the only thing that I can say until you can post the code. Your project() call is being used incorrectly. You also need to add the path to Qt5GuiConfig.cmake to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: Until I can see the issue, this is the only help I can provide. For future reference, follow the asking question guide if you need assistance. Because it's hard for others at times that can't download files (ISP/Work/etc firewalls) and have to guess what the issue is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve